# SQL Split Concept

Tags: sql, split

Split data and insert into new row.

I have this data:

[image]

I want to change the record like this,
mohan - male - 28 , Rajesh - male - 26 , Anjana - Female - 22 - convert onto three row.

Comment: Please edit your post in order to include sample data as well formatted text. Data in image form is hard to read and re-use.

Comment: Could here be multiple `~` for example: `Mohan~Rajesh~Mino | male~male~female | 28~26~29` ? Also what RDBMS are you using- *MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle etc*?

Comment: Use `unnest()` and `string_to_array()`